# How can I get my app listed in the Family - Creativity category in the Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play

All I see in the store listing for the type of an application is Applications and Games, none of those have the subcategory that I’m looking for. In fact there are many categories/sub-categories listed in the Google Play store that are not available in the developer console.

Is there something I need to do in order to enable all the supported categories?
Do those categories change by country?

[image]

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll take my chances, thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions regarding app distribution channels have been designated as off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).